# "This is the left eye": why not "a left eye"?

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

What is the difference in the application of the article before choosing the side? Or not at all (in what cases)?

> a left

or

> the left

Well, for example, such an example: "this is **a** / **the** left eye". Why can't we use the article "a" here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Left** is an adjective. It has no impact on the sort of article you want. Are you talking about an eye that wants a definite article, such as the abstract left eye, or when comparing the left to the right (such as on a single person)? Then use the definite article. If it's just any old left eye, use the indefinite.

Adding adjectives to a noun does not affect what article you use (unless it changes which form of the indefinite article is needed, naturally).

Comment: Does this rule also work when choosing a side to which you can go or turn, etc.?

Comment: In a sense. When you're saying "take a left", or "take the next right", there's an implicit "turn" after the direction.

Comment: @Boyep For additional clarity, In *turn left*, *left* is an adverb, not an adjective. And *left* can also be a verb in other contexts.